# Call Custom function in joomla plugin by url.

Tags: ajax, plugins, joomla, joomla3.0

I have created a system plugin in joomla and created a custom method that is `mymethod()`. Now i want to call this method via ajax. I have tried [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170127/how-to-use-joomla-ajax-interface-for-my-own-plugin) but it will create new ajax plugin but i want to call system plugin custom method not create new plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the plugin system event `onAfterInitialise()`.

Use this url for ajax: `index.php?type=mymethod`

This leads to:

```
function onAfterInitialise() {
  $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;   

  if($jinput->get('type')=='mymethod') {

    // your code here

  }

}
```

Comment: but this method may make that custom function available for all to call from url???

Answer (score 2):

The link is ok. You just need to change the folder name from ajax to system. Prior to joomla 3.4 it was mandatory to place your plugin in ajax folder but now you can place in any folder. Your code will look like this

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('system');
$plugin     = ucfirst($input->get('plugin'));
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();

try
{
    $results = $dispatcher->trigger('myMethod' . $plugin);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $results = $e;
}
```

Follow rest instruction as given there.